# Safe to do parallel JDBC insert inside foreachPartition using 2 scala Futures?

Tags: multithreading, apache-spark, concurrency, spark-streaming

I currently have a Spark streaming app which inserts into MySQL database. I'm following the pattern of

```
dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  rdd.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords =>
    val connection = createNewConnection()
    partitionOfRecords.foreach(record => connection.send(record))
    connection.close()
  }
}
```

that is found in the [spark streaming documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html). The thing is I'd like to modify it as such,

```
dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  rdd.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords =>

    val f1 = Future {
      //insert data to database 1
      val connection = createNewConnection(db1_config)
      partitionOfRecords.foreach(record => connection.send(record))
      connection.close()
    }
  }

  val f2 = Future {
    //insert data to database 2
    val connection = createNewConnection(db2_config)
    partitionOfRecords.foreach(record => connection.send(record))
    connection.close()
  }

  //await for both f1 and f2 to finish

}
```

and actually, I found that this works but I want to make sure I'm not shooting myself in the foot. I tested this in my app using **1 executor and 1 core** and found that both futures work in parallel when I'm using the global Execution Context. So I'm assuming that the global Execution Context gave 2 threads to work on. But where do those 2 threads come from? When I submitted my Spark job to YARN I specified 1 executor and 1 core. When I do LSCPU on that machine I find that I have 2 Threads per core. So am I using those 2 threads on that core or does the global execution context give me available threads from another core? I just want to know if this is a safe pattern and not "steal" threads from other applications.